# What is the right Lebesgue space $L^p_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ to which the function $\frac{1}{\vert x\vert}$ belongs?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

In dimension $3$, what is the right Lebesgue space $L^p_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ to which the function $\frac{1}{\vert x\vert}$ belongs?

There is a general rule that involves the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the function $\frac{1}{\vert x\vert^{\alpha}}$ and the right $L^p_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to which $\frac{1}{\vert x\vert^{\alpha}}$ belongs?

Comment: The only issue is the origin, seeing as how the function is locally bounded at every other point. Integrating in polar coordinates is probably the fastest route to deducing the formula. See corollary 2.25 on page 79 of Folland's *Real Analysis* (the second edition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B(0,1)$ denote the unit ball in $R^n$ and $\omega_n = |B(0,1)|$. Then the integral

$$ 
\int_{B(0,1)} \frac{1}{|x|^\alpha}dx = \omega_n\int_0^1 \frac{1}{r^\alpha}r^{n-1}dr = \omega_n\int_0^1\frac{1}{r^{\alpha-n+1}}dr 
$$

converges if and only if $\alpha-n+1<1$, i.e. $\alpha < n$.

From this you can deduce what you are interested in, namely that $\frac{1}{|x|^\alpha} \in L_{\rm loc}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if and only if $\alpha p < n$.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is the origin.  It is continuous, and therefore bounded everywhere else on any compact set not containing the origin.  By a change of variable, we are interested in the $p$ for which the integral below exists, 
$$\int_{0}^{\rho} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \left( \frac{1}{r} \right)^{p} r^{2} \sin(\phi) d \theta d \phi dr$$
We find that whenever $p < 3$, this is, 
$$4 \pi \frac{\rho^{3-p}}{3-p}$$
And moreover, the integral doesn't exist when $3 \geq p$.  And so $\frac{1}{|x|} \in {L_{loc}^{p}}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$ whenever $p<3$.